# Google Analytics Regex for 'And'

Tags: regex

I have setup 12 goals funnels setup in the following way

> 1st Step (and required)    /virtual/diabetes
>
> 2nd  Step  /personnel-info
>
> 3rd Step   /Review

All the 12 goals have the same destination `/payment/Thank-You` .

What I get is 12 goals with identical results.

I would like to track each goal separately hence I would like the destination to be the Regular Expression of, say, `/virtual/diabetes AND /payment/Thank-You`.

Now, my question, how do I write the Regular Expression of /virtual/diabetes AND /payment/Thank-You?

Comment: Try `/virtual/diabetes|/payment/Thank-You`

Comment: Is there anything else in the path names that you can use to differentiate the goals, like Query parameters? That would be easiest I believe, considering you have so many goals that are identical. Regarding your question, how do you have a destination goal with both the first step and the last step in the same url? Sorry, I'm not really understanding your request.

Comment: /virtual/diabetes|/payment/Thank-You would 'OR' what I want is 'AND'. To reach the destination page the visitor must have seen the two pages. There are no Query parameters. Destination goal must have the two URLs since some people who visit /virtual/diabetes do not complete or move on to other goals (such as /virtual/constipation). The two URLs clearly indicate that the visitor has visited the two pages. Or is there another way?